# Listar POSTS no WordPress pelas visualizações

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Preciso fazer com que: `<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>` liste de acordo com a quantidade de *views* (`post_views_count`), é como se fosse pra listar posts populares só que ele vai entrar na tabela `mh_postmeta`, e listar de acordo com que tiver mais *views*.

[image: tabela wordpress de post meta]

O pessoal utiliza o `'orderby' => 'comment_count',` para listar de acordo com os comentarios, mas preciso que ele busque pela outra tabela, **porém**, isso só pode acontecer para determinada categoria. Digamos que tenha 40 **CAT** ele só deve listar pelos **VIEW** em vez da **DATA** na **CAT 3**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você tem que fazer uma consulta um pouco mais complexa, o que vai te levar a procurar uma solução além do *loop* principal (i.e., `<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ; ?>`), mas isso não é tão problemático assim. Vamos lá:

O WP faz qualquer tipo de consulta por posts através da [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). O uso do loop conforme visto nos *templates* mais básicos está, por baixo dos panos, usando a global `WP_Query`. Em alguns casos mais específicos, a instância global não atende, por isso você tem que criar a sua.

O segredo está em saber com quais parâmetros você deve alimentar o construtor da nova `WP_Query` para que ela traga o que você quer. Você precisa limitar a categoria (vamos assumir que ela tenha o `ID` 3), e ordenar pelos `meta_value`s
 de uma certa `meta_key`. Isso fica

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
        'meta_key'      => 'post_views_count', //a sua meta key
        'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'         => 'DESC', //ou ASC, você que escolhe
        'cat'           => 3
    )
);
```

Com isso, o *core* do seu *loop* fica:

```
while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
    //só partir pro abraço
}
```

Após o uso de uma consulta feita sob medida, é sempre bom você resetar as globais, pra evitar conflitos. Isso é feito com

```
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Acredito que assim você atinja o que procura.

**EDIT**

Como citado nos comentários, eu havia citado o método de reset incorreto. Editei a resposta para que ela esteja coerente.

Comment: O [correto](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) depois de uma `new WP_Query` é `wp_reset_postdata()` 

Comment: @brasofilo bem observado. Resposta já editada

Answer (score 0):

Olá, essa solução do caio é muito boa e realmente da certo agora caso queira um filtro por Data, por exemplo: Quero exibir os mais vistos dos últimos 15 dias.

Eu fiz o seguinte código, se alguém puder melhorar agradeço.

```
<?php
            $query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT p.ID, pm.meta_value, p.post_date, p.post_content, p.post_title FROM wp_postmeta pm, wp_posts p WHERE p.ID = pm.post_id AND pm.meta_key = 'views' AND p.post_type = 'post' AND pm.meta_value <> '0' AND p.post_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15 DAY) ORDER BY CAST(pm.meta_value as DECIMAL) DESC LIMIT 5");
                //var_dump($query);
                    foreach ( $query as $news )
                        {
                            //echo $news->ID."<br>";
                        $args = array('posts_per_page' => 1, 'p'=>$news->ID); //exibindo o artigo do de um determinado ID.
                        // The Query
                        $my_query = query_posts($args);
                        global $post;
                        foreach ($my_query as $post) {

                         <!-- COLOQUE AQUI OS DADOS DO ARTIGO PARA REPETIR -->

<?php 
                        }

                        // Reset Query
                        wp_reset_query();

                   }; 

                        ?>
```

Abraços.